# C - scanf,printf name and age program

Tags: c, printf, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
   char yourname;
   int yourage;

    printf("Whats your name?\t");
    scanf("%c",&yourname); 
    printf("How old are you?\t");
    scanf("%d",&yourage);
    printf("You are %d years old and your name is %c\n\n\n",yourage,yourname);
    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

I want this program to ask for the username and age, and then print them..

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Did you read documentation of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) ? Did you search some examples of `scanf` in some free software?

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: `fflush(stdout);` ? or The name is not a single character. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use `scanf`, `%c` is intended to get a single character. If you want to get a string, you need to use `%s`.

Also, in C langage, string are just char arrays. So you need to declare a char array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
   char yourname[100];
   int yourage;

   printf("Whats your name?\t");
   scanf("%s",yourname); //i let you read the doc to avoid overflow :)
   printf("How old are you?\t");
   scanf("%d",&yourage);
   printf("You are %d years old and your name is %s \n\n\n",yourage,yourname);
   system("pause");
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Nit - strings are not "just `char` arrays"; in C, a string is a sequence of character values followed by a 0-valued byte.  Strings are *stored* in `char` arrays, but not all `char` arrays contain a string.

Comment: Thanks but if i change 100 to 0 or 1 or 2 this dont affect the program.. why?

Comment: If you put 0 all character put will overwrite data somewhere. If you write data in memory that isnt allocated for your program, it will crash.
char yourname[100] allocated you array, then, `yourname` is a pointer somewhere in the memory, and the next 100 cells are allocated for you array.

And dont forget strings have a null terminated char at the end ('\0'). So always keep and extra cell for this.

Comment: @SpirosKmaris: C doesn't do bounds checking on array accesses; if you write past the end of your array, you will wind up clobbering whatever follows it.  This may or may not result in a run time error, depending on what gets clobbered (buffer overruns are a common malware exploit).

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   char yourname[20];
   int yourage;

    printf("Whats your name?\t");
    scanf("%18[^\n]s", yourname);

    yourname[19] = '\0';
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("How old are you?\t");
    scanf(" %d",&yourage);

    printf("You are %d years old and your name is %s\n\n\n", yourage, yourname);

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```